# How do I use on_member_update to perform an action once a user obtains a specific role?

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

So basically I want my bot to use on_member_update so that when an user obtains the "verified" role it sends a dm. So far my code is-

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.roles) != "verified":
        if str(after.roles) == "verified":
            user = member.id
            channel = client.get_user(user)
            async with channel.typing():
                time.sleep(2)
                await channel.send("Verified")
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. The bot doesn't print any errors either, so I suppose that something in the code is not right in such a way that the condition isn't met. Yeah, the condition that i actually wrote, and not the one I actually mean of course. So, how can I twist my code so that it does what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

Compare both Role lists to see which role was added, check if the role name is the role you need then send them the message.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    added_role = set(after.roles) - set(before.roles)
    verified = None
    for r in added_role:
        verified = r

    if verified.name == "verified":
        await after.send("You have been verified.")
```